# Text Covered by AdView in offline mood due to black background

Tags: android, themes, adview

In my layout there is an AdView. When I choose Dark Theme with background color as black (#292929) in **offline mode**, there is a black blank space at the place of AdView. AdView shouldn't be there unless there is internet connection. So, my text is covered by that blank space. But if I don't assign any background color, everything is okay. **Now, how can I remove this blank black space due to AdView when background color is black?**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <item name="android:background">#292929</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item> 

</style>
```

Additional problem: during black background color, when I use magnify glass whole screen becomes black

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. I should delete it now but might be helpful for others. Instead of choosing background, windowBackground color  code solve the problem.

```
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
```